# Static field initialization in Java

Tags: java

I encountered this problem when doing a question on LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/print-in-order/

Consider two submissions:

1.

```
class Foo {
    private static int signal = 0;
    public Foo() {}

    public synchronized void first(Runnable printFirst) throws InterruptedException {
        // printFirst.run() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
        printFirst.run();
        signal += 1;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void second(Runnable printSecond) throws InterruptedException {
        while(signal != 1)
            wait();

        // printSecond.run() outputs "second". Do not change or remove this line.
        printSecond.run();
        signal += 1;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void third(Runnable printThird) throws InterruptedException {
        while(signal != 2)
            wait();

        // printThird.run() outputs "third". Do not change or remove this line.
        printThird.run();
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

2.

```
class Foo {
    private static int signal = 0;
    public Foo() {signal = 0;}

    public synchronized void first(Runnable printFirst) throws InterruptedException {
        // printFirst.run() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
        printFirst.run();
        signal += 1;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void second(Runnable printSecond) throws InterruptedException {
        while(signal != 1)
            wait();

        // printSecond.run() outputs "second". Do not change or remove this line.
        printSecond.run();
        signal += 1;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void third(Runnable printThird) throws InterruptedException {
        while(signal != 2)
            wait();

        // printThird.run() outputs "third". Do not change or remove this line.
        printThird.run();
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Try submitting these two and you'll find submission 1 will result in *Time Limit Exceeded*  while submission 2 will be accepted.

The only difference is that in submission 2, I explicitly added a statement `signal = 0;` to initialize the static variable. It should play no difference as I have already given this variable a default value in `private static int signal = 0;`, so what is going on here. Is there any subtleties in the static field initialization in Java that I did not know?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why did you choose to make the field static? What's the difference between a static field and a non-static field? What happens if you create two instances of Foo?

Comment: What do you mean with `submitting these two`? And `Time Limit Exceeded` and what/when is it `accepted`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LeetCode runs several different test cases against your solution. Let's assume that LeetCode is running a single JVM and running all the test cases in that JVM, but it is instantiating a new `Foo` for each case.

When running the first case, `signal` is zero, and your code works as expected. But at the end of this test case `signal` is now 2, because the test case increments it twice. Since it is static, it is shared among all instances of `Foo`. Even though LeetCode instantiates a new `Foo` for the second test case, the static `signal` is still 2. The `first` method increments it to 3, but then the test hangs because the condition `while (signal != 1)` is always true.

Initializing `signal` to 0 in the `Foo` constructor has the effect of resetting `signal` before the second and subsequent test runs.

There's no reason to make `signal` static here. It should be a regular non-static member so that each instance of `Foo` gets a new `signal` initialized to zero.

Comment: Thank you... My bad, I didn't notice "The same instance of Foo will be passed to three different threads." I thought each thread will have a different instance.

Comment: If each thread had a separate instance of `Foo`, your solution wouldn't work, even with a static `signal`, because your methods are not static and therefore synchronize on the class instance. Given instances `foo1` and `foo2`, it's perfectly fine for `foo1.first` to run concurrently with `foo2.second` since they are different instances.

Comment: @Slaw That's what he was trying to accomplish, sharing `signal` among the three `Foo` instances.